# looking for line containing specific string and added it into a new file

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is look for the string "`ESTABLISHED`" within my text file. If it is found, it will print the entire line onto another txt file `newestFile`. Problem is, it only looks for the first line that contains the string "`ESTABLISHED`", and saves it onto `newestFile`. I want to be able to copy and paste each line containing that string, not just one.

Here is my text

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)        rxbytes    txbytes
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50860      72.21.91.29.http       CLOSE_WAIT         892        691
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50858      www.v.dropbox.co.https ESTABLISHED      27671       7563
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50857      162.125.17.1.https     ESTABLISHED      17581       3642
```

and my code:

```
def script(file, newestFile):
    with open(file, 'r') as r:
        for line in r:
            if "ESTABLISHED" in line:
               with open(newestFile, "w") as output:
                  output.writelines(line)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open(newestFile, "w") as output:
    output.writelines(line)
```

In each loop you are re-creating `newestFile`. 
Write mode (`w`) deletes the file and creates new one if there is one. So on each time it finds `ESTABLISHED`, your code deletes old one and creates new one.

Instead of `w` use append(`a`) mode which will create new file if there isn't one and if there is a file, it will just append your values to the file.

```
with open(newestFile, "a") as output:
    output.writelines(line)
```

You might want to read more from docs on [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)